# Button event to Listview and back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have an android program. It has a button which when clicked is supposed to open up a listview of various strings.

But the problem is, as soon as I click on the button, the listview opens up, but my original android program crashes. ( ListView is in another class which now begins to run).

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MemoryReader.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
```

This is the code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

Also, the thing I want is that I click on the button, a checkbox list opens up, I select various things and then come back to the original screen.

The idea I had right now was to implement a listview with checkboxes ( I read somewhere, this is possible) and then use the getAllCheckedOptions() function to retrieve whatever was checked.

IF there is a simpler way to tackle my problem, please point me to there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "my original android program crashes"? Is there a force close dialog?

Comment: I am calling the ListActivity from my main Activity ( where the buttons were being displayed). The main Activity is crashing. And I have the ListActivity in my Android manifest- that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting for a result without the possiblility to tell where the result is coming from. It is not good. Change 0 for smth else better.

Here are some pieces of my working code that calls an activity for result:

------------------------------------- **PackVideo** activity --------------------------------------

**calling for ServerSetActivity**

```
Intent serverSetIntent = new Intent();
serverSetIntent.setClass(this, ServerSetActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(serverSetIntent, CHANGE_IP);
```

**constants setting and result catching:** 
(I have them together, because only here in catching both costants meet)

```
static public int CHANGE_IP = 1000;
static public int CHANGE_IP_DONE = 1001;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // If the request was for CHANGE_IP and the request was CHANGE_IP
    if (resultCode == CHANGE_IP_DONE && requestCode == CHANGE_IP) {
        readBaseInfoFromServer(getApplicationContext());
        startVideoPlayerService(getApplicationContext());
        setCurrentChannelAndPlay(getApplicationContext(), 0);
    }
}
```

----------------------------------- **ServerSetActivity** ----------------------------------------

**ending of the called activity**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(PackVideo.CHANGE_IP_DONE, intent);
finish();
```

Put here "onCreate" and *both* layouts of MemoryReader, please.

Comment: MemoryReader was nothing but http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html  Just a dummy hello list code for now to test. And what do I change 0 to? I tried a couple of different options ( randomly picked ) but the result was same.

Comment: In the example you are telling about, there is no layout for the list as a whole. Do you have it?

Comment: Understood from your example and worked it out. Thanks mate! :)